# is it safe to delegate the app signing process?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm new to app developing I just have a simple question. I have a problem with signing my app before uploading it to the play store so, can I send my project to someone to sign the app for me or it's not safe?

Comment: It's easier if you use intellij to build the app

Comment: Do you mean like an actual person or a build tool like appcenter?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, the question you're asking is not what stackoverflow is mainly for. Rather you can ask about the problem you're facing while signing your app. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend it because of what a sign implies. You are basically delegating someone else your responsibilities, but also all the work you did on the project and you expose it to major risks.
Moreover, signing an apk/bundle is pretty straightforward and you will find plenty of tutorials on the web.

The time you will spend doing that will not be wasted, since you learned something.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You are very welcome! Feel free to mark it as the best answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You are handing over complete control over your app to them. They can modify and then sign your app without you even knowing.

Also, you can never ever upload an update to your app if you don't have access to the signing key. They can refuse to sign an update or lose the key, which leaves you in a really bad position.

I think it's worth the time to learn how to sign an APK (either with Android Studio or through the CLI), as you will need to do that every time you want to update your app. Imagine how much time you'll lose asking your friend signing every update.

Here is a great tutorial on how to sign your app with Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't know that it would be that dangerous to delegate this process, again thank you very much